# ASP.NET Model Binder ignoring Bind(Exclude) and Bind(Include) and sets List<> to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-binding

i have a problem with the ASP.NET Model Binder and (entity framework lazy loading) or ignoring form fields...

### Important things

**Model `Category`:**

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        SellingRange = new Range();
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Range SellingRange { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Model `Product`:**

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Max length of name is 255.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**Model `Range`:**

```
public class Range
{
    public DateTime? Opening { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Closure { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Post Action:**

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(Category category, [Bind(Prefix = "SellingRange")] Range sellingRange, Guid[] products)
{
    category.SellingRange = sellingRange;

    // [...] ***********************************************************************************
}
```

**Submit data from html form:**

```
Id=dd1e055d-f851-4880-a88a-cfa01e8b2cd6
Name=Test
SellingRange.Opening=01.12.2014
SellingRange.Closure=24.12.2014
products=79174475-5640-45ac-bb88-c983c4de5324
products=6fc64b68-e5f3-4ca3-9cf7-56237b16561a
```

**View:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Category>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="stackoverflow.test" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#products').tagsInput({ autocomplete_url: '<%= Url.Action("ProductsAC") %>' });
    });
</script>

<%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) %>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name) %>:<br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Name) %><br />    
<br />  
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Products) %>:<br />
<input name="products" id="products" value="<%= String.Join(",", Model.Products.Select(product => product.Name).toArray() %>" /><br />
<br />
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SellingRange.Opening) %>:<br />
<%= Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.SellingRange.Opening).ToHtmlString() %><br />
<br />
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SellingRange.Closure) %>:<br />
<%= Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.SellingRange.Closure).ToHtmlString() %>
```

**Top view:**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
{
    %><% Html.RenderPartial("CategoryForm", Model); %><%
}
```

### Problem:

The entity framework not loading the category products at the ************** above. (After [...]) (In Controller)
As default the "Products" should be a `new HashSet<Product>();`. But the Model Binder mades them `null`.
I tried to add `[Bind(Exclude="products")]` in front of `Category category`. -> Not working!
Then i tried to include everything which is important... Adding `[Bind(Include="Id,Name")]` in front of `Category category`. Not working!

Is it possible to add `ICollection<Products>` directly from post array which contains only GUID's from the products? That would be nice! :)

**Or how to fix the problem?** I need a complete product list of the original product.
Something like... `DbContext.Categories.Find(category.Id).Products` which is not null ;)

I dont know why the Model Binder cant exclude/include the products AND let them be a `new HashSet<Product>();`. Why the Model Binder must set the products to null?

In debug mode the `category` variable in controller is a ProxyClass of Category which is fully loaded (i think) except the Products...

### Why i split the category and products

Because i check the products of the original product and after checking that i add the products of the Guid[] list. There i can load the products from the database and adding the products to the list. You can look at the sellingRange for example. The selling range is added by me because the Model Binder can't bind the `ComplexType` which has two `DateTime?` to the Range-Class and so i do this manually.

That works with the `sellingRange` ... Because i not need the original sellingRange... And because i not need them it could be null... But the products shouldnt!

## Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean _the Model Binder can't bind the ComplexType which has two DateTime? to the Range-Class_? Of course it can, and it can also bind to the `Products` collection. There is no need for the last 2 parameters. You need to show your view.

Comment: I've updated the question. There is the range class and the view now. I'll hope it helps you to helping me :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JQueryUI().DatepickerFor()` and the  `ToHtmlString()` at the end seems odd, but using Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.SellingRange.Opening) will certainly bind to `Category` when you post back. I see no reason why `JQueryUI().DatepickerFor()` would not (try without the `ToHtmlString()`.

Comment: Without `ToHtmlString()` shows `JQueryUI.Datepicker` on frontend and quellcode... It's like `<input type="text" name="SellingRange.Closure" id="SellingRange.Closure" />` for example. What's with the products? the SellingRange is not important. It works with the second parameter. But the Products-List is null which is a problem :( The Model Binder should load the complete entity by the Id.

Comment: As for the products, there is no point doing this. You don't change the data so sending it to the client and then back again is unnecessary, degrades performance and opens you to over-posting attacks. You have the `CategoryID` so just get the associated products from the repository when you post back. And why do you have things like `DisplayFor(m => m.Name)` followed by `TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`? Or is it actually `LabelFor()`?

Comment: The newest MVC available for VS2013 shows DisplayFor and TextBoxFor. Also i must manually load the category and foreach the GUID[] to add the Product to Category? Is there no way to exclude Products from ModelBinder so that the ModelBinder loads the Products from Database?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I loaded the category manually from DbContext and the lists are null, too!? Do you know how to load them?

Comment: If you really do want the products, then `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++) { Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Products[i].ID) }` (but its bad design). And you don't need the second parameter - check the value of `category.SellingRange.Opening` - its already bound!

Comment: That's an EF issue an not my field. You would need to ask a new question for that

Comment: No the category.SellingRange is null... And i mean i would get the products in the controller! Not in the view ^^ I tried this: `Category cat = DbContext.Categories.Find(category.Id);` but cat.Products is null! Why!?

Comment: If the control has `name="SellingRange.Closure"` I assure you it will be bound when you post. As for why `cat.Products is null` I don't know

Comment: I tried it a few seconds ago... `SellingRange` => {stackoverflow.test.Range}` and the Range have `Opening` => null and `Closure` => null. Whats wrong with my model binder!? Post parameters contains `SellingRange.Opening=01.12.2014` and `SellingRange.Closure=24.12.2014`...

Comment: OK - think I spotted it, your question shows that your posting `SellingRange.Opening=01.12.2014`. That's not a valid `DateTime` format that could be bound - it would need to be `01/12/2014`. Are you setting some specific format in the datepicker?

Comment: No. Should i add the DisplayFormat attribute to the datetime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67227/discussion-between-patrickb-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an deep nested DefaultModelBinder... I dont know that there was one.

I have a valid Document and the ModelBinder of the project overwrites everything with null.

The custom ModelBinder ignores the [Bind(Exclude)] and Include, too!
Because that i have so much problems.

Thanks @Stephen Muecke.
Now the bindings works correctly with one parameter ^^
I optimized the custom ModelBinder :)